# What are good use cases for an in-process events system vs microservices with a broker?

Tags: java, event-handling, messaging, microservices

I've seen recently that there are different frameworks out there that allow the use of a messaging architecture but implemented in process, both using same and different threads. The ones I know about are Spring, Guava EventBus and Reactor.

My question is about what are good use cases where someone would want to use them instead of sending messages to a full fledged broker. I understand that its usage allows for a better decoupling of the business logic but in a microservices architecture you would normally publish events to be consumed by other microservices. The advantage of that is the failure tolerance you have by adding a cluster of brokers where an erroneous message cause by a failure in an instance can be retried by another one. Implementing logic that is decomposed and executed by sending messages that are later consumed by the same system, specially when the subscribers are executed in different threads, seems to me difficult to then put the data back to a consistent state.

Answer (score 0):

Advantages of microservices over in-process is not really in the change it represents for message consumption.

Microservices allow you to execute portion of your code on specific nodes within a cluster, permitting to allocate the heavy calculations on powerful computers and secondary or light resources on less powerful resources. Overall it allows you to balance the performances better and scale your resources on the portions of code that require it.

Also, whenever you update the code of a micro-service you do not impact the other services, so that your changes (and errors) are isolated. If everything runs within the same process any wrong update might actually render the entire solution unusable.

In the end, getting the communication out of your process (3rd party broker) allows you to share it with more people, agents, processes, etc. Otherwise people have to become part of your process (a module?) and this is really not efficient.

Honestly, the only good reason you have for intra-process communication within your monolithic is for speed (in-memory communication rather than on-the-wire communication).

Comment: I don't agree with the last point. Designing a system that relies on internal messages to improve speed to me hints that it doesn't actually need it. Relying on an external broker to dispatch messages provides a way to scale the system up by just adding new instances. That way, any instance could pick a message up and continue with the process, adding failure tolerance when combined with retry for messages not processed after a node failure. If each message sent is part of a chain of events, one message lost may disrupt the whole system, which an external brokers cluster helps fix.